# Reading a file and updating the content

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Basically i have a concern, which needs to be solved using Objective C alone. (i have tried with C)

Is there any appropriate way in objective C to read character by character (till EOF) from a file, The file is got from document directory or bundle.

Problem : So, If i want to append a escape character () before all inverted comma's in a file and A special character (say /) before each line.

Replace

```
(type == "Currency")
```

with

```
/(type == \"Currency\")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be this helps you.

**I assume your file contains only string data not JSON or XML**

```
 NSString *strFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"pathofyourfile" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 NSLog(@"strFileContent %@",strFileContent);
 NSString *newStr = [strFileContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"/("];
```

Like last line you can replace your data.

Hope this works for you.